# Setting parameters for gamma_distribution using boost

Tags: c++, boost, random, boost-random, gamma-distribution

I am trying to use the Gamma distribution from Boost 1.5. 
Now I want the value of *k* and *theta* to be 4 and .5 respectively.
But I get a compile error whenever I set the value of *theta* < 1.

```
/usr/local/include/boost/random/gamma_distribution.hpp:118: boost::random::gamma_distribution<RealType>::gamma_distribution(const RealType&, const RealType&) [with RealType = double]: Assertion `_beta > result_type(0)' failed.
```

Is there any way to get around the same?

Comment: Without posting a small self-contained example code snippet, it is very hard to debug your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not pass the parameters correctly to the distribution function. Here is the C++11 version (Boost works equivalently):

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{   
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    double alpha = 4.0;
    double theta = 0.5;
    std::gamma_distribution<> gamma(alpha, 1.0 / theta);
    auto value = gamma(gen);

    // May print: 6.94045.
    std::cout << value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Note the parametrization:

- `alpha` is the same as `k`
- `beta` the inverse scale parameter and is the same as `1 / theta`.